# Is it possible to modify a collection of controls in c# windows form ? How?

Tags: c#

The C# windows form has 8 buttons.
I want to change the text of each button. Those texts are random numbers without repetition. I know how to generate random numbers without repetition but I don't want write 8 instructions to assign each number to each button text respectively like this:

```
                   button1.Text = listNumbers[0].ToString();
                   button2.Text = listNumbers[1].ToString();
                                     .
                                     .
                                     .
```

Is it possible to modify a collection of buttons in c# windows form such as using a loop? If yes, how to write these codes and their pseudocodes? Thanks.

Comment: You need to create a button collection and store each button in the collection. And then you access that button from the collection and change its property. You can also have a dictionary with buttonId as key and button object as the value. Then you can get the button object by its ID from the dictionary and change its property

Answer (score 0):

You can use form's Controls collection for changing text of buttons like below.

```
foreach(var control in this.Controls)
{
    if(control is Button)
    {
        ((Button)control).Text = "New Text";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ's `OfType<T>` with the `Controls` property:

```
foreach (var button in Controls.OfType<Button>()) // will only give you Buttons
{
    button.Text = "some text";
}
```

Comment: Thank you.what if i only change text of specific buttons only , how to write these codes?

Comment: @AlexGor9527 You can use LINQ's [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations)

Comment: Errr... This does not work. All the texts are same. Each text should be a unique number which is generated without repetition.

Comment: @AlexGor9527 I thought " I know how to generate random numbers without repetition" meant that you knew already how to generate the numbers

Comment: Those texts of buttons should be random numbers without repetition. However, when I used your method and assigned listNumbers[](array of random number) to each button, all the button texts was same. Maybe my bad description attributed to this mistake. Anyway, I have solved and thanks again.